# What is kGADSimulatorID and Where to Find it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I am trying to add Google Banner to my iOS app for the first time and I am reading the Google menu. https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#swift

It says that I need to add one line of code with my sample device ID:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers =
[ "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ] // Sample device ID
```

My simple but seemingly unanswered question is how do I find my own sample device ID then???

Now that my codes in my XCode project looks like this under ViewDidLoad of the correct page:

```
    bannerView?.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-31361704xxxxxxxx/94xxxxxxxx"
    bannerView?.rootViewController = self
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
    bannerView?.load(GADRequest())
```

And as I run is not returning any Google banners. I am imagining that after I fill in kGADSimulatorID which looks like a placeholder with a real ID, then I will be fine?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running it on the simulator? if you run on the simulator and is not getting any test ads, then this is rather weird indeed.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `[kGADSimulatorID as! String]`? `kGADSimulatorID` is of type `AnyObject` (for some reason).

Comment: I saw some other posts saying I should include "as! String" but as I did that on my XCode, it says that kGADSimulatorID is already String hence "as! String" has no effect at all and I should remove it

Comment: Huh, we might be using different versions of the SDK then... Anyway, `kGADSimulatorID` is the ID for the simulator, so if you run on a simulator, test ads should show up. Does it not?

Comment: That's delivered to the Console window if I remember correctly.

Comment: no the ID did not show up, the first statement I copied here was EXACTLY what showed up on the console. that prompts me to ask this question

Answer (score 2):

First go to "Add Additional Simulators"

[image: Add Additional Simulators]

Then select any of simulators from the list and you can find the identifier of that simulator.
[image: Select simulator]